# laravel 5.4 model creation

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I´m creating the model for my Laravel app and have a big doubt.
I have two tables: **users** and **groups**, and a many to many relationship in the Pivot table **group_user** (groupd_id, user_id).

This is the migration file for the pivot table ( I added more fields later):

```
    Schema::create('group_user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
        ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')
        ->on('groups')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I want users to upload N photos for every group, so I thought about creating a new table like this:

*group_user_pics (id, pict_name, pict_sort_order, ... ?)*

But Im not sure what is the best way to create a foreign key to **group_user** table since it has 2 id´s, or if there is a better solution than creating a new table.
Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: From what I understand your photos should be related to both group and user, so you'll know which user uploaded which photos to which group. So you can add 2 columns user_id and group_id to your photos table or make a pivot table which will link user_id, group_id and photo_id.

Comment: Ok thanks TheFallen. i think im going to try the first option, adding 'user_id' and 'group_id' as foreign keys in the photos table